# convert javascript regex expression to swift nsregularexpression

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I am new to Swift programming.

I have a valid regex in javascript, I need the same functionality in swift

```
str.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, '');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Swift 2.3:

```
let str = "A+B/C===="

let result = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "-")
                .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/", withString: "_")
                .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\=+$", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)

print(str)
print(result)
```

#### Swift 3:

```
let str = "A+B/C===="

let result = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\=+$", with: "", options: .regularExpressionSearch)

print(str)
print(result)
```